# Google maps is blank in https

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

My google maps is a blank white screen now my websites using https protocol. In HTTP the maps were fine, but I recently forced my site to use https protocol with redirects in Cpanel. ive been trying to solve this for couple weeks now and appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Google maps was working fine before, whilst I was on HTTP, I did, however, change the script source link to the API key in my HTML to the new v3 but I could be wrong. Also, the htaccess file has now changed in an attempt to force https.
In my javascript file, the reference to google maps has changed but not sure if its to the old v2 or the new v3. Thank you in advance.

Html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/selectivizr/1.0.3b/selectivizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key</script>
<script src="resources/js/gmaps.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.4.8/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
/*maps*/

var map = new google.maps.map({             !line 29!
    div: '.map',
    lat: 52.760514,
    lng: -1.6500,
    zoom: 12
});
```

developer error messages

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
>      script.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'com' of undefined
>      at HTMLDocument. (script.js:29)
>      at j (jquery.min.js:2)
>      at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>      at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
>      at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)

HTML

```
<div class="section">

    <div class="map-box js--section-map">

        <div class="map" id="map-1"></div>

        <div class="form-box" id="form">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>Get in Touch</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <form method="post" action="mailer.php" class="contact-form">

                    <div class="row">

                        <?php
                        if($_GET['success'] == 1) {
                            echo "<div class=\"form-messages success\">Thank you! your message has been sent.</div>";
                        }

                        if($_GET['success'] == -1) {
                            echo "<div class=\"form-messages error\"> Oops! something went wrong. Please try again!</div>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Is there really a space here? `https:// maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key`?

Comment: Hi, no theres no space that is my fault through editing the post.

Comment: `new Map.google.com` ... that looks wrong ... `Map` is a javascript object that would have nothing to do with google ... did you mean `new google.maps.Map` ... like every single working google map in the internet?

Comment: Apologies, not sure why I wrote it that way but thanks for pointing that out, I have now changed it but i still have a blank screen.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix the typos and provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your actual problem.

Comment: Removed unnecessary code and typos hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The main error seems to be addressed in the comments and was fixed by using `google.maps.Map`

From the [Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) and my own use, try the following to get something to show

```
var map = new google.maps.Map($('.map')[0], {
    center: {lat: 52.760514, lng: -1.6500},
    zoom: 12
});
```

Comment: Hi Cameron, I've swapped and tried your script but still google maps is still a blank white space.

Comment: @ollie Can you post all your HTML? Assuming you have a `<div class="map"></div>` element somewhere.

Comment: Cameron sorry for the late reply, had no laptop. here is my HTML map and partial form.

Comment: @ollie Do you have any styling on the map div? Assuming no more errors in the console, try `<div class="map" id="map-1" style="height:640px;width:640px;"></div>`

Comment: Cameron, I do have styling on the map and form. but also now ive swapped my js to yours im now getting google API key error. unfortunately the original errors are still there, but now its no longer white blank space but the error from google coming up.

Comment: @ollie try removing the other imports (especially the gmap.js file, is that the google maps API again?)

Comment: Cameron, I did temporarily remove imports still no change but now the console Telling me it’s a HTTP referrer issue and that I haven’t added it to the api restriction list but I have. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @ollie No idea sorry. Only advice is make sure the domain and everything is correct. If that issue persists, try making a new question.